# Liferay screens can be used to create mobile screens in the WCM and push to mobile applications?

Tags: android, sdk, liferay, liferay-6

Liferay screens can be used to create mobile screens in the WCM?

And if it is then how it is used to push to mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a web content and render it in an application using Liferay Screens.

But the developer flow is the other way around, you create an app linked to a specific content (and can be dynamically linked with Audience Targeting or your own code) and Liferay Screens renders that content. You can change the portal content and Liferay Screens will download it (and lets you control the policy of the cache).

The content rendered will be native if there is a screenlet that supports that type of content (like DDL forms or login/signup...). Or you can render a webview/browser with an adapted template for mobile phones.